# Вложенный запрос с уникальными значениями и фильтрация результата по дате

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT 
    date, 
    url, 
    description 
    LIKE "%t%" AS emails, 
    description LIKE "%s%" AS http,
    user
    FROM `table`
    WHERE `field` = "test"
) AS tbl
WHERE tbl.date BETWEEN CAST('2022-04-01 0:00:00' AS DATETIME) AND CAST('2022-04-30 23:59:59' AS DATETIME);
```

Запрос заработал, но есть не уникальные значения, повторы по url, emails, как при выборке за апрель, если запись уже была в марте, не выводить её в выборке за апрель?

```
CREATE TABLE logs ( 
    id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
    date datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    url text DEFAULT NULL, 
    actions text DEFAULT NULL, 
    field varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL, 
    description text DEFAULT NULL, 
    user varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL 
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

```
INSERT INTO logs (date, url, actions, field, description, user) 
VALUES('2022-04-01 0:00:00', 'site.com', 'update', 'Contacts', 'site@site.com', 'admin');

INSERT INTO logs (date, url, actions, field, description, user) 
VALUES('2022-04-30 0:00:00', 'site.com', 'update', 'Contacts', 'site2@site.com', 'admin')
```

Здравствуйте, я получаю определенные данные уникальные и мне нужно их отфильтровать по дате, если я делаю это сразу, то получаются в первую очередь выводятся дубликаты, а мне это не нужно, нужно чтобы если например в запись была изменена в марте, а потом в апреле и выводя информацию за апрель, эта запись не попадала в результат, т.к она уже была затронута в марте , как так сделать?

Comment: Ни хрена не понять. Выложите пример данных - CREATE TABLE, INSERT INTO (5-7 записей) и требуемый для этих данных результат. Не забудьте указать **точную** версию MySQL. PS. В полях `emails` и `http` будут исключительно 0, 1 или NULL - вот тебе точно нужен ТАКОЙ результат?

Comment: Нужен именно такой, 1 или 0.
Мне нужен просто пример подобного запроса, чтобы по результату одного запроса можно было отфильтровать по дате.

Comment: Ну сам запрос верный, во всяком случае синтаксически. Правда неясно, нахрена нужен подзапрос... ну и неизвестно, соответствует ли он поставленной (но не озвученной) задаче.

Comment: Просто mysql выдает ошибку, жалуется на WHERE, если его убираю, он начинает жаловаться на подзапрос.
Как бы по сути весь этот запрос, отвечает нужным мне требованиям, но он не работает, починить бы его.

Comment: Читаем мой первый комментарий, предложения 2 и 3.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `logs` (
  `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `url` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `actions` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `field` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;

INSERT INTO logs (`date`, `url`,  `actions`, `field`, `description`, `user`) VALUES('2022-04-01 0:00:00', 'site.com', 'update', 'Contacts', 'site@site.com', 'admin');

Comment: INSERT INTO logs (`date`, `url`,  `actions`, `field`, `description`, `user`) VALUES('2022-04-30 0:00:00', 'site.com', 'update', 'Contacts', 'site2@site.com', 'admin')

Comment: Ну почему в комментариях-то??? неужели самому не видно, какая лапша получается? Под текстом вопроса есть ссылка "Править" - жми на неё и вставляй всё в текст вопроса. С форматированием. Можно пометить как Update или там Дополнение...

Comment: Поправил шапку.

Запрос заработал, но есть не уникальные значения, повторы по url, emails, как при выборке за апрель, если запись уже была в марте, не выводить её в выборке за апрель?

Comment: Добавить в запрос соотв. WHERE NOT EXISTS, проверяющий, что нет записи с тем же (url, emails) но с более ранним месяцем.

Comment: А можно пример пожалуйста.